# How To Change Enemy Speed or make it stop after a few second from spawning. and moving again after a few second in GDscript

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I don't Know How to Make The Enemy change speed or not moving after a few second here my code

```
extends CharacterBody3D

const speed = - 1
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

func _physics_process(delta):
    position += transform.basis * Vector3(speed,0, 0) * delta * 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### `SceneTreeTimer`

If you only need this change a few seconds after spawning, creating a timer is useful, in particular an `SceneTreeTimer` comes handy:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    var timer := get_tree().create_timer(a_few_seconds)
    timer.timeout.connect(func(): velocity = Vector3.ZERO)
```

Where `a_few_seconds` is the amount of time you want to elapse before the change happens.

As you can see I'm using an anonymous method (lambda) to set `velocity` to `Vector3.ZERO`, you could use multiple lines, or connect a full blown method.

No, you do not need to keep a reference of the `SceneTreeTimer`. I'm using a local variable to avoid making the line too long.

By default the `SceneTreeTimer` will run even if the game is paused (which you do with `get_tree().paused = true`), but you can have it stop when paused like this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    var timer := get_tree().create_timer(a_few_seconds, false)
    timer.timeout.connect(func(): velocity = Vector3.ZERO)
```

---

### `Time.get_ticks_msec()`

However, if the time at which you want the change to happen might change, you are better of using a different approach.

My go-to these days is computing the time at which I want it to happen having `Time.get_ticks_msec()` as starting point:

```
var change_msec:int


func _ready() -> void:
    change_msec = Time.get_ticks_msec() + int(a_few_seconds * 1000.0)
```

And then checking in `_process`:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if Time.get_ticks_msec() > change_msec:
        velocity = Vector3.ZERO
```

A variation of this is using `float`, which also allows to encode `INF` for something to never happen:

```
var change_seconds:float


func _ready() -> void:
    change_seconds = (Time.get_ticks_msec() / 1000.0) + a_few_seconds


func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    if (Time.get_ticks_msec() / 1000.0) > change_seconds:
        velocity = Vector3.ZERO
```

The drawback of this approach is that... It takes extra effort to support pause (you could listen `NOTIFICATION_PAUSED`, and `NOTIFICATION_UNPAUSED`, and keep track of accumulated time). It is probably better to change approach if that is important.

---

### `delta`

Some people prefer a countdown and take advantage of `delta`.

```
var remaining_time:float


func _ready() -> void:
    remaining_time = a_few_seconds


func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    remaining_time -= delta
    if remaining_time < 0.0:
        velocity = Vector3.ZERO
```

This is probably the easier to grasp.

---

### `Timer` (from the editor)

The above method is also how a regular `Timer` works behind the scenes, so that is another option:

- Add a `Timer` in your scene as a child to your `Node` in the editor.
- Configure its `wait_time` to the few seconds you want to wait.
- Set its `autostart` property to `true` so it starts automatically.
- Connect the `timeout` signal to your `Node`.

Then you will have a method that handles the `timeout` signal looking like this:

```
func _on_timer_timeout() -> void:
    velocity = Vector3.ZERO
```

---

### `Timer` (from code)

Of course, the above implies that you have a scene where you can do that. If you don't you can still make the timer from code:

```
var timer:Timer

func _ready() -> void:
    timer = Timer.new()
    timer.wait_time = a_few_seconds
    timer.timeout.connect(_on_timer_timeout)
    timer.start()

func _on_timer_timeout() -> void:
    velocity = Vector3.ZERO
```

And, of course, `SceneTreeTimer` is a convenient way of doing that. So we have come full circle.

---

### `Thread`

There is arguebly another way of doing it: start a `Thread` and have it sleep with `OS.delay_msec` for the desired amount of time, then it can use `call_deferred` or `set_deferred` to do the change you want.

The only advantage of this approach is that you are not checking every frame in `_process`, but of course a `Thread` has its own cost, so this might only make sense for the case of a long wait time. It also has the caveat of not supporting pause.